# Simple To do List

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple to do list  and i was hoping if a experienced person could review my code in hope for feedback. I don't use any libraries as i haven't taken time to look about them. I decided to stick with plain js.

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Thank you for the reply, now i'm looking into the semantics in html and fixing my code. ;)

```js
let i = 1;
function myFunction(){
    n = i.toString();
    let theInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if(theInput == ""){
         return false;
}
    else{
    let input = `<li class = list id = div${n}>` + theInput +`  <button onclick = myFunction2("div${n}")>Done</button>`;
    newDiv = document.createElement(`div${n}`);
    newDiv.innerHTML = input;
    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div0");
    currentDiv.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv.nextSibling);
    i++;
    }
}

    const myFunction2 = function(id){
        let dou = document.getElementById(id)
        dou.remove();
    }


    const myFunction3 = function(className){
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

```css
    
    h1{ 
        font-family: Kufam;
        font-size: 50px;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 12px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align:  center;
    }


    .list{
        font-family: Kufam;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>To do List</title>
<header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kufam" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todoliststyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functionList.js"></script>
    <h1>
        <br>To do List <br>
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="what to do" required maxlength="50">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" >Add</button>
            <button onclick="myFunction3(`list`)">Clear All</button> <br><br>
        </h1>

    <div id="div0">

</header>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

Your app seems to be working :) Good job and keep going ! Take a look at the below notes. I will try to add more a bit later.

- Treat Your variable name as instructions for other developers (and yourself from future). They should be descriptive. Function with name such as  `Function2` are not acceptable
- Your HTML inputs do not have associated labels
- You use `h1` in a wrong way. It's not a proper tag to place the input in. Use a `div` instead. H1 is used to define (only one) main heading on Your page. Read about HTML semantics and the meaning of each tag
- some of your `let` variables could be changed to `const`s. The rule is as follows - use `const` whenever it's possible and if it's not - use `let`
- Do not style elements by their tag names like `h1{}` add the proper class to the element and style it with `.className` syntax in Your CSS
- Instead of an `onCLick` inline event listener in Your HTML You could add this handling in the js file using `element.addEventListener('typeOfEvent', callback)`
- Add descriptive `ID's` to the elements - `div0` means absolutely nothing
- Your whole logic is in the `if/else` statement. Try to move it outside
- To DO title should not be in the `br` tag. Use a header or a `p` instead
- Your script logic could be also improved -> I will try to describe more a bit later
- You could also use a shortcut for border styles `border: 12px solid black`

Answer (score 2):

### Coding style

- Format your code with correct indent. Format your HTML with correct closing tags.
- Name your variable / function / DOM elements with some meaningful names. Not `myFunction1` nor `div0`.
- You declared `myFunction` as global one, but use `const` for `myFunction2`. I would suggest use same style for every functions.

### HTML

- If you are posting a snippet, skip `<!doctype html>` and `<html>` would be acceptable. If you are posting whole HTML, make sure to include `<head>`, `<body>`, `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tags.
- Add `lang` attribute to your HTML, maybe on `<html>` element.
- `<h1>` is used for title of page. Not for input. Use proper tags.
- `<li>` should only be placed under `<ul>` or `<ol>`. It should not be placed under `<div>`.
- Use common HTML tags if available. In case you need custom tags, use name with `-` in it. For example, `<todo-list-item>` is acceptable (but not preferred), but `<div1>` is not.
- When you need custom tags or using `<div>` try adding `role` on it to make it more meaningful.

### JavaScript

- Save a reference to DOM elements, so you do not to `getElementById` every time some event triggered.
- Never, never, never feed `innerHTML` with constructed string values. Especially something from user input. It may cause XSS issues.
- Add event listeners with `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` attribute is preferred.
- When button [Done] is clicked, you removed the `<li>` item but keeps its parent in DOM. It should be a mistake.

### CSS

- Use `margin` / `padding` to locate items. Do not use `<br>` and space character (U+0020).

### Others

- Wrap input in a `<form>` and listen to `submit` event instead of `click` event. So user may add the todo item with an Enter key. (Don't listen to keyup / keydown / keypress events, they may be confused with IME.)
- Clear the input when an todo item is added successfully. So user may add next item without clean the input manually.